# Javascript/JQuery, determine the pixels per inch

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen, screen-resolution

I found the width and height of the screen with the following commands

```
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

I tried to find out the physical diagonal in inch with the following commands

```
var dpi_x = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetWidth;
var dpi_y = document.getElementById('testdiv').offsetHeight;
var width_in = screen.width / dpi_x;
var height_in = screen.height / dpi_y;
var diagonal_in = Math.round(10 * Math.sqrt(width_in * width_in + height_in * height_in)) / 10;
```

The problem now is, that it doesn't work anymore when I change the screen resolution. Is there any way to get the physical dimensions of the screen via javascript/jquery?

Comment: All dimensions are in px. Physical size in cm/inches etc are of no interest to javascript.

Comment: Whereas CSS allows lengths to be specified in `in`, `cm`, `mm`, `pt` and `pc`, actual rendered lengths are nominal. A screen pixel density of 96dpi is assumed. See the section titled "CSS units and dots-per-inch" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I think you should post that comment as an answer.